# ¿Se pueden quitar las comillas del resultado de un input en Python?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Es mi primera vez escribiendo aqui, pero requiero de su ayuda (ya que estoy algo estancado jeje).

Básicamente estoy creando un CRUD, donde el código de inserción de data, eliminación de la misma, realizar querys y demás ya tengo listo. Sin embargo, trato de crear un código para modificar una fila, este código en cuestión utiliza inputs para que el usuario final pueda elegir que filas modificar y que data insertar. Pero me aloja el siguiente error donde se puede visualizar que el problema es que el campo que queremos cambiar trae '' (comillas simples):

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''id' = '12' where id = 1' at line 1")
```

PD: Antes de visualizar el código, si tienen alguna sugerencia tipo que librerias usar instead o algunas practicas que podría emplear en mi código se lo agradecería! (Me encuentro aprendiendo y en algunos casos no sé por donde empezar más que mis ideas xd)

```py
import pymysql


def run():
    try:
        conexion = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                user='admin',
                                password='',
                                db='proteccion_civil')
        try:
            with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
                consulta = "UPDATE registros SET %s = %s where id = %s;"
                input_field = input('Qué quieres modificar?: ')
                input_sin = input_field
                input_change = int(input('¿Qué n° id deseas buscar para modificar?: '))
                input_update = input('Escribe los cambios que quieres realizar: ')
                cursor.execute(consulta, (input_field.replace("\'","") , input_update, input_change))
            conexion.commit()
        finally:
            conexion.close()
        
    except (pymysql.err.OperationalError, pymysql.err.InternalError) as e:
        print("Ocurrió un error al conectar: ", e)

run()
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esas comillas son agregadas internamente por pymysql, no vienen con el input.

El error se debe a que, cuando un valor está entre comillas, mysql lo interpreta como cadena, no como columna.
Si quieres crear una consulta dinamica en pymysql tendrás que usar [formateo de cadenas](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/formateo-de-cadenas/).

Entonces el código dentro del with quedaría así:

```
input_field = input('Qué quieres modificar?: ')
input_change = int(input('¿Qué n° id deseas buscar para modificar?: '))
input_update = input('Escribe los cambios que quieres realizar: ')

cursor.execute(f'UPDATE registros SET "{input_field}" = %s where id = %s;', (input_update, input_change))
```

Como podrás notar, puse el nombre de la columna entre comillas dobles. A diferencia de Python (donde las comillas simples y dobles hacen lo mismo), las comillas dobles en mysql indican que lo que está entre ellas va a ser el nombre de una columna o tabla. Esto lo hago para dificultar la [inyección sql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). En lugar de suceder la inyección sql, el programa fallará.

**Nota final**: Te recomiendo evitar en lo posible el formateo de cadenas para crear consultas sql. Esto se debe a que, si has leido el link de inyección sql que te dejé, el usuario podría crear su propio query no deseado dentro de tu query.
Otra cosa. A menos de que estés haciendo un administrador de bases de datos mysql, te recomiendo colocar restricciones al input `input_field` (por ejemplo, que solo sea valido si la columna ingresada está en una white list). Por que incluso con las medidas anteriores, es posible la inyección sql. El usuario podría intentar modificar, por ejemplo, la columna id, y quizá no te gustaría que el programa permita eso.